# How to make the admin approve some data from the database to move from table to another?

Tags: database

I have a database table data
these data are added by some users..
I have created a login system for the admin
I need the admin to approve some data from the users if approved make a copy of them to another table 
if not keep them in the same table

Ex: users can comment .. if the admin liked their comments .. comments should be moved to another table ...if the admin refused the comments it should stay in the same table of the database